# How do I find running programs that are not visible?

Tags: skype

This is NOT a request for killing applications.

I can well kill all process, no matter what. That's not the issue.

The issue is:

When we "close" Skype or Banshee, or Korganizer or many many others, it is common that, after we do that, **we have an icon on the panel (near the clock).

However, that has not been the case here.

Once I do that, I have no icon on the panel, near the clock, as a result, I can't easily re-display the application window as normally should happen.

How can make those icons appear on the panel ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have your "Notification Area Applet" in your panel? that's the place where all the applications goes when minimized to tray or closed while running (as in the case of banshee, rhythmbox and many more).

I would also suggest you to have the "Indicator Applet" http://launchpad.net/indicator-applet in order to have a different tray for having useful applications at the reach of a clic.

This applets can be added to your panel, by right clicking on it and choose "Add to Panel", then simply identify those applets that you need, and drag them to the panel.

Give this a chance and please let us know if this helps.

Comment: I've not read your answer yet. I wanted to add that, this same issue happens with Korganizer. I would like to see it on the system tray, but they don't appear. I have Skype 2.2.25 Beta I believe. But as mentioned the same happen with OTHER programs.

Comment: In the System Monitor, have you tried the menu "View", option "All Processes"? see my update. This will show you all the processes, which may include those hidden. Please inform.

Comment: Please have a look to my second update. Thanks.

Comment: Now I get your point. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

First install the package *wmctrl*

Then open a Terminal and run.

```
 wmctrl -a skype
```

That should make the window visible. If it doesn't work run

```
wmctrl -l
```

look for a matchinhg window title and replace *skype* in the first command with the window title

Comment: Thks. Please have a look into my update. cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Run the command `ps -aux` in a terminal and you will see a list all the open processes your machine is running. The second column indicates the PID of each process, and you can kill any process using `kill [PID]`