# So how can I check if a progam is running?

Tags: system-tray

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do we found running programs that are not visible?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40128/how-do-we-found-running-programs-that-are-not-visible)

I have installed 64 bits Bitdefender on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64 bit.

After updating the virusdefinitions I clicked on the 'hide' button.

Now I am wondering if Bitdefender is still running.

So how can I check if bitdefender is running?

Comment: Have you tried restarting the program?

Comment: Can I ask why you installed an anti virus?

Answer (score 2):

open a terminal and type `gnome-system-monitor`

it should be listed in the "Processes" pane.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that bitdefender was installed as a service you get the desired information with

```
sudo service bitdefender status
```

If that comes back with an error, you can play it lazy and just type `sudo service bit` <kbd>tab</kbd> to autocomplete without having to type the full name. (if there exist more services with names starting with `bit` you press <kbd>tab</kbd> twice to get a list of possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ps command to list running processes eg:

```
ps -A
```

You can then use grep to filter the results for what you are looking for:

```
ps -A | grep defender
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the `exe` link in `/proc/[0-9]*`, thusly:
    `sudo ls -l /proc/[0-9]*/exe`